# error handling in swift - no params or wrong params

Tags: swift, error-handling

Here's a simple code. How do I set a default value if something is wrong?

```
enum direction {
    case north, west, east, south
}

let defaultDirection = direction.north

func printDirection(parameters: [Any]) {

    let dir = parameters[0] as! direction
    //if error then dir = defaultDirection

    switch dir {
      case .north: print("north")
      case .east: print("east")
      case .west: print("west")
      case .south: print("south")
    }
}

printDirection(parameters: [direction.east])
```

For example, if I call without parameters `printDirection(parameters: [])` or if I store not a direction type value `printDirection(parameters: [7])`

Comment: What you expect in function printDirection? Only print directions?

Comment: Why is parameters an array of `Any` rather than an array of `direction`?

Comment: It's Any because I want to pass another parameters with different types. Here it's just an example.

Comment: `guard parameters.count > 0, let dir = parameter[0] as? direction else { print("north"); return }`, instead of the `let dir = ... as! ...` line, for instance.

Comment: You are responsible for *if smth is wrong*. The best solution is to write reliable code. For example rather than a unspecified array use a custom struct with distinct (non-optional) types. Then the compiler helps you to recognize design mistakes at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you can't catch any errors if the method is not marked with `throws`. Therefore, you should check each of these (array length, cast) with if statements.

```
let dir: direction
if let firstParameter = parameter.first? as? direction {
    dir = firstParameter
} else {
    dir = defaultDirection
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are force-casting as a `Direction` an element that is **not** a `Direction` then you will definitely get an error at some point.

The code:

```
let dir = parameters[0] as! Direction
```

is definitely not a good idea here.

What you could do instead of force-casting, is building your object using the `rawValue`, and taking care of the case when your element doesn't exist so that it doesn't return `nil` (*which is the default behavior*).

Say you have an enum of fruits:

```
enum Fruit: String {

    case apple = "apple"
    case banana = "banana"
    case mango = "mango"
    case cherry = "cherry"

    init(rawValue: String) {

        switch rawValue {
        case "apple" : self = .apple
        case "banana" : self = .banana
        case "mango" : self = .mango
        case "cherry" : self = .cherry
        default: self = .apple
        }

    }

}
```

As you can here I use the my enum's `init` to return "apple" anyway whenever the value is not something I want.

And now you can do :

```
 let fruit = Fruit(rawValue: "pear")

 print(fruit) // Prints "apple" because "pear" is not one of the fruits that I defined in my enum.

 let otherFruit = Fruit(rawValue: "banana")

 print(otherFruit) // Prints "banana"
```

And of course you can use it in your function in a similar fashion :)

Note: Please note that you would still have to handle the case when your fruit name is **`nil`** (or **any other type that is not a String**) because the `rawValue` **does need** to be a `String`. You could use a if or a guard statement to check whether it's a `String` or not before trying to build your fruit using the `rawValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is:

```
let dir = (parameters.count >= 1 && parameters[0] as? direction != nil) ? parameters[0] as! direction : defaultDirection
```